# Aborting an MFC-based C++ without a dialog pop-up

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, abort

We have an old MFC-based C++ gui app (Visual Studio 6.0) which often does not terminate correctly.  So I would like to be able to use a instruction like "abort();" to immediately end it.

However, the abort() instruction causes a dialog box to pop up, rather than ending immediately.  Using "exit(int)" doesn't work.

Is there a way to eliminate the abort dialog, or is there a better termination method?

Comment: *which often does not terminate correctly* -- Maybe it's time to update to a newer compiler, or fix the bug(s) causing the application to terminate incorrectly.

Comment: What does the popup look like (what message) when you call `abort`. I tried it in an MFC app and I don't see one. Just a rapid exit.

Comment: There's also `ExitProcess` which just tells Windows to exit the process, no mucking about.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious way to abort without anything else happening ahead of time would be for it to call the Windows ExitProcess function:

```cpp
ExitProcess(exitCode);
```

If you want to kill it from some external program, you'd do that with `TerminateProcess`. To do that, you'll need a handle to the process, which typically means getting its process ID. If you're doing this from a program that spawned the one you want to kill, you'll probably get a handle to it when you create it. Otherwise, you'll probably need to use something like `FindWindow` to find its window, then `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to find the ID of that window's process. Once you have that, you call `OpenProcess` to get a handle, and finally `TerminateProcess` to actually kill it.

Comment: That, or just [SetErrorMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode) as desired, and just keep using [std::abort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort).

Answer (score -1):

If it is a dialog box based app, then you can use EndDialog(IDOK) method.

Comment: The OP *clearly* explained that their application doesn't properly terminate. Telling them to use what works for a program that properly terminates is not useful.